# Sequel::AdapterNotFound: LoadError: cannot load such file -- win32ole

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, ruby-on-rails-3, sequel

I am successfully able to connect to `MySQL` and `Postgres` database using `'sequel'`.

I want to connect to the SQL Server database from Ubuntu 12.04 to Windows machine. Using tiny-tds we can do that, but I want to use 'sequel' for connection

Gem Installed

```
gem 'dbi'
gem 'tiny_tds'
gem 'sequel'
gem "win32ole-pp"
gem "rubysl-win32ole"
gem 'activerecord-sqlserver-adapter'
```

I am getting following error.

```
1.9.3p448 :007 >   require 'win32ole-pp'
LoadError: cannot load such file -- win32ole-pp

1.9.3p448 :008 > require 'rubysl-win32ole'
 => false 

1.9.3p448 :001 > DB = Sequel.ado(:database => 'test_database', :host => 'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx', :user => 'username', :password => 'password', :provider => 'SQLNCLI10')
    Sequel::AdapterNotFound: LoadError: cannot load such file -- win32ole
```

Sequel provides adapter for tiny tds. How I can use that adapter? Please tell me how I can do that with sequel gem?

I am not getting how to use tiny tds with sequel, as sequel is providing adapter for tiny_tds.

Thank you...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Finally I am able to connect to remote MSSQL database from ubuntu 12.04 machine with help of sequel. Sequel uses tiny_tds for connecting to SQL server database. Here xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx is ip address of remote machine. No need for `win32ole`

Sequel provide adapter for MySQL2, Postgres, SQL Server and Tiny tds.

Gem Required

```
gem 'tiny_tds' #For SQlServer
gem 'mysql2' #For MySQL
gem 'sequel'
```

If you are connecting to MySQL2

```
DB = Sequel.connect(:adapter => 'mysql2', :user => 'username', :password => "passw0rd", :host => "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx" , :database => "test_database")
```

If you are connecting to SQL Server

```
DB = Sequel.connect(:adapter => 'tinytds', :user => 'username', :password => "passw0rd", :host => "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx" , :database => "test_database")

post = DB.from(:test_table)

post.all
```

Comment: I thought it wouldn't be necessary to install the mysql2 gem because it seems that [sequel already included an adapter](https://github.com/brianmario/mysql2#sequel). But problem is gone after installing the gem. Thanks!